# OpenCV color correction

Tags: android, ios, opencv, computer-vision, apple-vision

I'm working on a project that involves a paper strip that changes color from white to dark brown based on certain factors, and I need to write an app that is able to classify this color. I have already written the feature recognition part of it in OpenCV, however I'm  having troubles accounting for different lighting conditions. I have included a rectangle that contains 6 different color: black, white, and 4 different shades of gray on the strip to aid me in the process. However I'm still struggling with getting the true color of the indicator. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please include your code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Well, I haven't done anything yet, since I have no idea where to begin. Right now I have a method that takes a photo of the strip, does some image analyzes and returns an object containing 6 colors extracted from the photo, in bgr format (1 byte per channel). The colors are: sample color, black, white, light gray, gray, and dark gray. For all of them except the sample color I know the true bgr values. I need to be able to calculate the true bgr value of the sample color.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting task. You can try to start from some simple approach, for example using linear algebra and least squares minimization.

We can consider true and registered colors as 3D vectors (I assume you work with color images in RGB or some other color space) and effect from lighting as a matrix operator (3x3).

Each pair of colors creates a constraint of a following form:

[image], where [image] is operator you are looking for, [image] is real color, and [image] is observed color.

You can rewrite these constraints in another form:

[image]

where [image] are components of [image] (notation for observed color is analogous).

This form allows us to combine multiple observations simply by stacking matrices. You'll need at least 3 color matches to estimate the operator exactly, and more if you want to be robust to noise and other unwanted effects.

After you form matrices according to your observations, you can solve a set of linear equations in a least-squares fashion to obtain you operator [image] (mapping from real colors to observed ones).

Once you estimate the operator, you can just premultiply any color you observe with [image] to get real color.

This is a simple to understand and effective approach, but it has some drawbacks.

First - it assumes that there's a linear relationship between real and observed colors, which may be an incorrect assumption (I haven't made experiments to check it).

Besides, even if the lighting acts as a linear operator - since the camera dynamic range is fixed - you may encounter problems once some color would go out of range due to bright lighting, since the clipping this will produce makes the operator non-linear.

Also, you should carefully select the colors for your marker (I would pick colors with different hues to capture the basis of color space, besides they should be in the middle of dynamic range to reduce the probability of going out of range). Don't forget that if components of your colors would be too correlated (if you use shades of gray, for example) - observation matrix may lose rank and become singular, which will make solving for elements of **A** impossible/meaningless.

I've made a simple python script to check if the operator I described can be estimated in simple conditions (homogeneous 2x darkening). It can also be useful for experimenting with different colors for marker.

```
import numpy as np

# choose colors for marker
Cr = np.array([[10, 200, 30],
               [40, 50, 160],
               [10, 80, 90],
               [150, 60, 10]], dtype = np.float32)

# simulate effect from light
Co = (Cr/2)

# form a set of constraints for a color pair
def genConstr(pt):
    constr = np.zeros((3, 9), dtype = np.float32)
    constr[0, 0:3] = pt
    constr[1, 3:6] = pt
    constr[2, 6:9] = pt
    return constr

# form constraints for all colors on marker
cs = np.zeros((0, 9), dtype = np.float32)

for i in xrange(Cr.shape[0]):
    cs = np.vstack((cs, genConstr(Cr[i, :])))

# estimate operator
Ai = np.linalg.lstsq(cs, Co.flatten())[0].reshape((3, 3))
A = np.linalg.inv(Ai)

#display results
print 'operator:'
print A

print ''

print 'reconstructed colors:'
for i in xrange(Co.shape[0]):
    print A.dot(Co[i])
```

It produces following result:

```
operator:
[[  2.00000000e+00  -3.12988124e-16  -3.83156015e-16]
 [ -1.77322970e-32   2.00000000e+00  -3.60822483e-16]
 [  9.82882077e-17  -4.07302066e-16   2.00000000e+00]]

reconstructed colors:
[  10.  200.   30.]
[  40.   50.  160.]
[ 10.  80.  90.]
[ 150.   60.   10.]
```

As you can see, estimated operator is quite close to theoretical (2s on main diagonal), and real colors are reconstructed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed write up. After trying this method on some of my sample pictures I can say that, unfortunately, it doesn't work. From my observations it seems that the relationship between real and observed color is not linear - brighter color observations seem to deviate more from the true color than the darker ones.

Comment: You can share some of your testing data then, to get more relevant answers :)

Comment: Here are two sample pictures taken with my phone http://imgur.com/a/68Hf2. Color of the circle inside of the black box is what I'm trying to classify. The true colors are: the box around the circle is black, so RGB (0,0,0), the brightest color on the big rectangle beneath the box is white (255, 255, 255), then (200, 201, 205),  (149, 152, 157), (100, 105, 109) and the darkest rectangle is (52, 60, 63). It has to be printed on a black and white printer, so I'm unable to make these rectangles anything other than greyscale.

Comment: I've played a bit with your sample and tried to correct the colors with affine transform, so that the brightest and darkest rectangles have desired color. But the remaining rectangles still had wrong color. I guess best way to do this correction would be to use a spline to fit observed intensities to desired ones, but I don't have time to try that. Still may you may find this idea useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I will end up doing something like your spline idea. Fingers crossed it will work.